# Bubblesort decreasing size each time

Tags: c, bubble-sort

This code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 10

int main(){

    int a[SIZE]={2,6,4,8,10,12,89,68,45,37};
    int pass;
    int i;
    int hold;
    int dim=10;

    printf("Data items in original order\n");

    for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++){
        printf("%4d", a[i]);
    }

    for(pass=1; pass<SIZE; pass++){
        for(i=0; i<dim; i++){
            if(a[i]>a[i+1]){
                hold=a[i];
                a[i]=a[i+1];;
                a[i+1]=hold;
            }
        }
        dim--;
    }

    printf("\nData items in ascending order\n");

    for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++){
        printf("%4d", a[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

gives me this error:

```
Data items in original order
   2   6   4   8  10  12  89  68  45  37
Data items in ascending order
   2   4   6   8  10-98850560  12  37  45  68
*** stack smashing detected ***: ./prog terminated
```

Why? I don't understand. Please explain it to me. Thank you very much. I just don't get it. I don't understand. Please help me. I don't know what to do. Please.

Comment: You are accessing out of bounds. When `i` is 10 (value of `dim`), `a[i+1]` is an invalid access.

Comment: `int dim=10` --> `int dim = SIZE-1`

Comment: @user3386109 But SIZE is 10. Saying dim=SIZE-1 is like saying that dim=9 which I don't need. I need dim to be 10.

Comment: Arrays in C are 0-indexed. Meaning you need to iterate from i=0 to i<SIZE. If you plan to access index `[i+1]` inside the loop, you need to iterate up to `i<SIZE-1`. And that's all there is to it.

Comment: https://taas.trust-in-soft.com/tsnippet/t/a9e64056 shows the out-of-bounds access that has already pointed out. Changing `dim` to `dim-1` leave the code without undefined behavior (for this input) and it produces the correct result (for this input): https://taas.trust-in-soft.com/tsnippet/t/c7281f2f

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
 if(a[i]>a[i+1])
```

`i` can go upto `dim-1` and `dim` is 10. So when `i` becomes 9, the above expression becomes

```
if(a[9]>a[10])
```

You will be accessing the 11th element of an array which contains only 10 elements and thus you will access an out-of-bounds memory address. This is undefined behaviour.

From [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior):

> The behavior of some programming languages—most famously C and C++—is undefined in some cases. In the standards for these languages **the semantics of certain operations is described as undefined**. These cases typically represent unambiguous bugs in the code, **for example indexing an array outside of its bounds.**

Answer (score 0):

`stack smashing detected` means there is a buffer overflow in the stack, you basically went out of the bound of your array.

`int dim=10;` dim is 10

```
for(pass=1; pass<SIZE; pass++){  <<< First loop, dim is still 10
    for(i=0; i<dim; i++){        <<< i < 10
        if(a[i]>a[i+1]){         <<< Last loop : i=9
            hold=a[i];
            a[i]=a[i+1];;
            a[i+1]=hold;
        }
    }
    dim--;
}
```

> i=9  a[i+1] => a[10] which is out of bound

Hope that helps~~

Answer (score 0):

In statement : `if(a[i]>a[i+1])` when i = 9 (max 9 in this for loop), that time you are comparing `a[9]>a[10]`  but you defined array up to `a[9]`.

Modify that for loop as:

```
for(i=0; i<dim-1; i++)
    if(a[i]>a[i+1])
```